# How to display the message "Press Ctrl+Alt+Del so as to login" before displaying the login window

Tags: windows-xp, winlogon.exe

On some computers I have a security display that asks me to "press Ctrl+Alt+Del" so as I can go to the Login window with username password and so on, even at boot (I think so)...

But on some computers I don't have that message at boot.

Do you know of any parameter I can change so as to toggle between the two modes? (Displaying or not this security window).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it via [User Accounts in Control Panel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308226)

> - Log on to the computer as an administrator.
> - Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click User Accounts.
> - Click Change the way users log on or off.
> - **Click to select the Use the Welcome screen check box if you want
>     to disable the CTRL+ALT+DELETE
>     sequence**
> - Click Start, click Run, type `Control Userpasswords2`, and then
>     press ENTER.  Note You may receive the
>     following dialog box: You must be a
>     member of the Administrators group on
>     this computer to open User Accounts.
>     You are logged on as user name, and
>     this account is not a member of the
>     Administrators group. In this
>     condition, you are required to type
>     the user name and password when the
>     system prompts the dialog box to type
>     the user name and password of the
>     administrator of the computer.
> - Click the Advanced tab.
> - In the Secure logon section, click to clear the Require users to press
>     Ctrl+Alt+Delete check box if you want
>     to disable the CTRL+ALT+DELETE
>     sequence.